# Unable to download tomcat maven plugin?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven-2

I want to deploy a web-app to tomcat using maven. But i am getting an unable to download the tomcat maven plugin error.

part of my pom.xml

```
 <build>
    <finalName>cdmi-server</finalName>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <!--<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>-->
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager</url>
          <server>TomcatServer</server>
          <path>/cdmi-server</path>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
...
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>maven-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Maven 1 Repository (legacy)</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
      <layout>legacy</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>m1.dev.java.net</id>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
      <layout>legacy</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>m2.dev.java.net</id>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin,manager"/>
```

settings.xml(maven):

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>TomcatServer</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

The error i am getting, when I run mvn:install,

```
Project ID: org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin
Reason: POM 'org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:pom:2.0.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  m2.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/),
  maven-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1),
  m1.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/1)

 for project org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin
```

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: are u behind a corporate firewall??

Answer (score 4):

According to the official page, you need to change your plugin declaration:

> Since version 2.0-beta-1 tomcat mojos has been renamed to tomcat6 and tomcat7 with the same goals.
>
> You must configure your pom to use this new groupId:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

[source](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/)

The codehaus version [stopped at v1.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/tomcat-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 3):

General Advice

Visit maven central repository http://search.maven.org/

and search for the Class/Jar you need and get the latest/correct
artifact Id, group Id etc

to download the correct version of JAR file